# Prompt user to save my desired text file name

Tags: python, html, http

I wish when the user clicks on a link say.

http://www.xyz.com/dynamic-text.py

The browser will prompt user to save the text file.

The following script will make browser to prompt user to save `dynamic-text.py`. I wish to prompt user to save `some-file-name.txt`. How can I do so?

---

**dynamic-text.py**

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u

print "Content-type: text/text"
print

print "This is Text File"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the [Content-Disposition](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) HTTP header:

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=some-file-name.txt"
print
```

Also note that you should use the `text/plain` content type instead of `text/text` which, to my knowledge, doesn't exist.